# Emulate Cyanogenmod in Genymotion?

Tags: android, genymotion, cyanogenmod

I want to emulate a Cyanogenmod ROM and it seems Genymotion image is based on Cyanogenmod? However, the basehand is unknown in "Settings" -> "About phone".

If it is not, is there any official Genymotion Cyanogenmod image or where can I find a reliable Genymotion Cyanogenmod image?

Comment: Here? [Link](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/)

Comment: That link seems to be official CM image instead of Genymotion version. It will be much better if there is any existing Genymotion image build on CM.

Comment: True, but you question states: "is there any official Cyanogenmod image or where can I find a reliable Cyanogenmod?"..

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this, I changed my statement. Thanks, anyway.